# How to access values and fields from a Document List with Java MongoDB driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using the MongoDB Java drivers and I've been digging around for almost an hour now regarding how to handle Document Lists and get values from them but I haven't found anything that works for me.

Below is my relevant code section and the condensed down console output of the different Document Lists I have. If someone could explain how to basically make an array of my "scoregot" values it would be much appreciated because I can't make sense of anything out there.

```
    List<Document> englishOut = (List<Document>) englishCollection.find()
            .projection(Projections.include("scoreout")).into(
                    new ArrayList<Document>());

    List<Document> englishGot = (List<Document>) englishCollection.find()
            .projection(Projections.include("scoregot")).into(
                    new ArrayList<Document>());

    List<Document> assignType = (List<Document>) englishCollection.find()
            .projection(Projections.include("scoretype")).into(
                    new ArrayList<Document>());
```

[Document{{_id=5b3ec0d3beceb309d804ce7e, scoretype=quiz}},
Document{{_id=5b3ec18cbeceb309d804ce7f, scoretype=hw}},

[Document{{_id=5b3ec0d3beceb309d804ce7e, scoreout=25.0}}, Document{{_id=5b3ec18cbeceb309d804ce7f, scoreout=5.0}},

[Document{{_id=5b3ec0d3beceb309d804ce7e, scoregot=23.0}}, Document{{_id=5b3ec18cbeceb309d804ce7f, scoregot=5.0}},

Comment: Try `List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
            englishCollection.find().projection(Projections.include("scoregot")).forEach((Block<Document>) d -> { values.add(d.getString("scoregot")); });`

Comment: What is the purpose of the d -> just unfamiliar with that syntax. Looked it up and didn't really get this use case.

Comment: That is lamba expression syntax. For versions before java 8 you can use  `englishCollection.find().projection(Projections.include("scoregot")).forEach(new Block<Document>() {
                @Override
                public void apply(Document d) {
                    values.add(d.getString("scoregot"));
                }
            });`

Comment: Thanks for the help